# Why can't I apply Linearity of Expectation in this situation (in layman's terms)

Tags: probability

**Background**

- Let's say you own a convenience store
- Each day $N$ customers will visit you, where $N \in (1,7 \, billion \, humans)$
- $X_i$ is the amount that each customer will spend
- All the $X_i$'s are iid and also independent of $N$

Let's say you want to know the expected value of total revenue made in a day. I know the following is true (Wald's equation),

$$E \bigg[ \sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i \bigg] = E[N]E[X]$$

**My question**

Can you explain why it is illegal to do,

$$E \bigg[ \sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i \bigg] = \sum_{i=1}^{N} E[X_i] = NE[X]$$

I know this is illegal because $NE[X] \neq E[N]E[X]$. I know the LOE doesn't always hold for infinite sums but in this situation $N$ is capped by the human population. If you could explain in lay terms I would greatly appreciate it (versus going into sigma algebras and IUT). Thanks.

Comment: $N$ is a random variable.

Comment: The expected value of a random variable is a real number. Your attempt at using linearity gives a random variable because $N$ is random. So you aren’t even getting the right *type* of object when you apply linearity this way. It’s like saying 117 * 123 = Fish; I don’t have to do any calculation to tell you that it is wrong.

Comment: In order for us to explain why this is not an application of the linearity of expectation, it would help if you would first explain why you believe that it is.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I appreciate your help! Hmmm let's say I have a sum $3+3+...$ which goes on for $N$ times, then the expected value of this sum should be $3N$. Do you agree? For my problem, replace $3$ with $E[X]$ which should also be a constant. So it's $NE[X]$. Of course I know this is wrong but can you point out where?

Comment: The problem is already in the example with the $3$s. If $N$ is a random variable, then the expected value of an $N$-fold sum of $3$s is not $3N$ but $3\mathsf E[N]$.

Comment: @guy interesting... I hear what you're saying. But I know not all expectations yield a real number. For example $E[X|Y]$ is itself a RV. I'm not trying to be snarky... I appreciate your answer and will meditate on it...

Comment: @joriki hmmmmmm thanks that is helpful!! So in the following sequence, the first equality is incorrect. Would the second equality be correct given the first equality is correct? I think this will help me understand. $$E \bigg[ \sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i \bigg] = \sum_{i=1}^{N} E[X_i] = NE[X]$$

Comment: $N$ is a random variable: $E[X]N$ is a random variable. Expectations are numbers, not random variables.

Comment: @HJ_beginner: The second equality is correct. It's not correct "given the first equality is correct" (since the first equality isn't correct); it's simply correct in itself.

Comment: @joriki Thank you sir and to the rest of you. You are all doing god's work.

Comment: @HJ_beginner conditional expectations operators are not expectation operators. A conditional expectation is a random variable, and if you were taking the expectation conditional on $N$ then your result would be OK.

Comment: @guy Hmmm thanks that is helpful. When I first learned that $E[X|Y]$ is a RV it was a little disorienting. Up to that point $E[anything]$ was always a number. One follow up question... I believe $E[X|Y=42]$  yields an actual value and is not a RV. What would you call $E[X|Y=y]$, a conditional expectation operator evaluated at the point $y$ that yields a real number?

Comment: @HJ_beginner $E[X \mid Y = y]$ is a number, yes. There are a couple of ways to be rigorous about this; one is to start by defining $E[X \mid Y = y]$ and then define $E[X \mid Y] $ to be what you get when you "plug in" $Y$ for $y$. Alternatively, you can define $E[X \mid Y]$ first as a random variable, and then let $E[X \mid Y = y]$ be the value $E[X \mid Y]$ takes on the level set $[Y = y]$.